# Is there a way add auto completion (like QtCreator) and detailed syntax highlighting support for C++ to Atom or Sublime Text?

Tags: c++, eclipse, sublime-text, qt, atom.io

QtCreator has powerful support for both of these.

[image]

But it has no plugin for docked terminal like this (Eclipse);

[image]

And I don't want to use Eclipse because it has a lot of bug and it has more features than I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very cool editor: [Kdevelop](https://www.kdevelop.org/).

It has customizable terminal plugin and customizable syntax highlighting. And It is fast and lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there isn't plugin for auto completion, even in CodeBlocks IDE there isn't auto completion.
I think the closest about your question is the syntax highlighting support for C++ 
You can get for Sublime text like a package or download the code editor visual Studio Code in the next links:

1. [Visual Studio Code: Code Editor with C++ syntax highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview)
2. [C++ syntax highlighting Package for Sublime Text](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/C%2B%2B%20Starting%20Kit)

Comment: If you found an C++ auto complete for sublimeText, please shared

Comment: I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: Well, another option is NetBeans for ubuntu It has highlighted text and code assitance. in fact I think it's better than I previously recommended. Here is the link [Netbeans C++](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/).

Comment: `NetBeans` uses `Java` too. And It is IDE. I found `KDevelop`, It is lightweight, fast. And It's like IDE, but it's not :)

Comment: You can try CudaText - works ok on Ubuntu. Has C++ syntax too.